# form with toggle checkbox doesn't submit when toggle is off using Firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, vmware-clarity

I have a simple form which includes a toggle switch. It works when I enable the switch, but when I leave it off, the form won't submit.
This is my template code

```
 <clr-toggle-container>
      <clr-toggle-wrapper>
      <input type="checkbox" clrToggle [(ngModel)]="pocTimesheetRequired" name="pocTimesheetRequired"/>
        <label>Timesheet Required</label>
      </clr-toggle-wrapper>
    </clr-toggle-container>
```

this is my ts file

```
  pocTimesheetRequired: boolean;

  onSubmit() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
    if (this.name) {
       this.afs.collection('agencies').add(
        {
          // agencyId: this.agencyId,
          name: this.name,
          phone: this.phone,
          pocTimesheetRequired: this.pocTimesheetRequired
          // logoUrl: this.logoUrl,
          // benefitCardPhotoUrl: this.benefitCardPhotoUrl

        });
    }
  }
```

when I leave the switch off, there is an error as follows:

```
Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field pocTimesheetRequired in document agencies/XwIQmDrnj8ciZST0GmdM).
```

I feel like I'm missing something that should be obvious, but although I've gone over the docs and searched for an answer everywhere, I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message provides you with a reason:

> Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field pocTimesheetRequired...)

Meaning `this.pocTimesheetRequired` is `undefined` when sending the data to firestore.

Form control usually does not change the model value unless interacted with. Since `this.pocTimesheetRequired` is `undefined` during initialization, it's stays undefined until user clicks the checkbox.

To fix the issue I suggest you set a default value for it or replace it on submission:

Solution 1:

```
pocTimesheetRequired = false;
```

Solution 2:

```
phone: this.phone,
pocTimesheetRequired: this.pocTimesheetRequired || false 
// logoUrl: this.logoUrl,
```

You can use `?? false` as well instead of `|| false`.